# How do I properly share my Python Packages using Eclipse+pydev+egit?

Tags: python, eclipse, github, pydev, egit

So I have a few Packages that I have made and I want to share them with my friends and I want to put them in separate github repositories, now I know how to make a project in eclipse, I already have my packages in the project and I also cloned the empty github repository in my local computer now when i connect the project to the local repository and push it into github it actually copies the complete project into the repository but i want only the packages to be copied i.e.

right now its like githubrepository/pythonproject/pythonpackage
but i want it to be githubrepository/pythonpackage

can someone suggest a link or some ways to solve it?am i making a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

On git, you always work with the repo as a whole (even if you see only a part of it on Eclipse).

So, to do what you want, you have to actually create a new repo and copy the sources you want and then push from there (there are ways to do that with git saving the history too if that's important to you).

You might want to take a look at git submodules too...